# Redraw canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am making an Android 2.2 application using Eclipse. My application should draw 
images by clicking on buttons.

I have two buttons at the bottom of the screen, and I need to draw the shape in the same screen that has the buttons. I used `FrameLayout` in which the shapes are drawn.

My problem is, the two shapes are overwriting, so I need to redraw the canvas.

**My Code**

```
package draw.tab;

import android.app.Activity;
//import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class DrawActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    DrawView drawview;
    CircleView circleView;
    FrameLayout Frame;
    Button square,circle;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyFrame);      
        drawview=new DrawView(this);
        circleView=new CircleView(this);

        square=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);
        square.setOnClickListener(this);
        circle=(Button)findViewById(R.id.circleButton);
        circle.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.circleButton:
                Frame.addView(circleView);
                /*circleView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(40,100,20));
                circleView.findViewById(R.id.CircleViewId);
                setContentView(circleView);*/
                break;
            case R.id.buttonTest:
                Frame.addView(drawview);
                /*drawview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                drawview.findViewById(R.id.DrawViewId);
                drawview.layout(400,0,200,450);
                setContentView(drawview);*/
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**DrawView.java**

```
package draw.tab; 

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View
{
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    Path pat=new Path();

    public DrawView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        //context.clearRect(70,140,400,450);
        //pat.addRect(50,40,250,400,Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    public DrawView(Context con,AttributeSet atts)
    {
        super(con,atts);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {       
        //canvas.drawPath(pat,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(20,40,450,40,paint);//horizontal top            
        canvas.drawRect(70,140,400,450,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(20,40,20,600,paint);//vertical left
        canvas.drawLine(20,600,450,600,paint);//horizontal bottom
        canvas.drawLine(450,40,450,600,paint);//vertical right
        //this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

**CircleView.java**

```
package draw.tab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CircleView extends View
{
    Paint p=new Paint();
    Path path=new Path();

    public CircleView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        //path.addCircle(250,250,50,Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    public CircleView(Context con,AttributeSet atts)
    {
        super(con,atts);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        //c.drawPath(path,p);
        //c.save();
        c.drawLine(20,40,450,40, p);//horizontal top
        c.drawCircle(250,350,100,p);
        c.drawLine(20,40,20,600,p);//vertical left
        c.drawLine(20,600,450,600,p);//horizontal bottom
        c.drawLine(450,40,450,600,p);//vertical right
        //c.restore();
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/MyFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <draw.tab.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/DrawViewId"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp">
    </draw.tab.DrawView>

    <draw.tab.CircleView
    android:id="@+id/CircleViewId"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp">
    </draw.tab.CircleView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">

     <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Circle" 
        android:id="@+id/circleButton" 
        android:layout_width="160dp">
    </Button>

    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Square" 
        android:id="@+id/buttonTest" 
        android:layout_width="160dp">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The above is all my code. The shapes are overwriting, so I want to remove and redraw the canvas or redraw without overwriting.

Comment: Difficult to solve your problem without seeing some code. Add  your class code.

Answer (score 4):

Try calling invalidate() on your view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this. But still the shapes r overwriting. I have two classes that extends view. DrawView.java to draw Square and CircleView.java to draw Circle. By clicking the buttons the shapes r displayed but the square shape overwriting circle. can u please help me to remove the canvas

Answer (score 0):

Call `canvas.save()` then do drawing then call `canvas.restore()`. Also depends on the bitmaps you are drawing. The bitmaps should have a transparent background.

### Edit

Call `canvas.drawColor(Color.White); //Or whichever bg color` before drawing the bitmap.

### Edit

In `drawview` try this

```
canvas.drawRect(getLeft(), getTop(), getright() , getBottom() ,paint);
```

Similarly in `CircleView`

```
canvas.drawCircle(getLeft()+getwidth()/2, getTop()+getheight()/2, 100, paint);
```

One last try. Set children gravity..

```
<draw.tab.DrawView
android:id="@+id/DrawViewId"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="600dp"
android:layout_gravity="left">
</draw.tab.DrawView>

<draw.tab.CircleView
android:id="@+id/CircleViewId"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="600dp"
android:layout_gravity="right">
</draw.tab.CircleView>
```

Comment: I used these code. But still it is overwriting. can u please tell me how to remove the canvas

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used these code. But still it is overwriting. can u please tell me how to remove the canvas. I have two classes that extends view to draw circle and square and an activity class to display the drawing by clicking the buttons and a main.xml file. Please help me to remove the canvas otherwise to redraw without overwriting.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but cant get exactly what I need. The shape is drawn in new screen.

Comment: Sorry. Now too I didnt get what I want. As your code, the circle is drawn and in the same canvas square also drawn. I need two canvas in a single screen without overwriting. can u please help me

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now atleast they should not overwrite each other.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. I need to remove the canvas and redraw. can u help me please

Comment: what do mean remove the canvas?

Comment: If I click the image only 1 image should be drawn. Now When i click the circle button, circle is drawn and after i click square button, the circle is there and square also drawn. So I want to remove the canvas in which the circle was drawn and then want to draw square in canvas. Please help me.